# How to calculate mean of a 1d numpy array which has both string and integers

Tags: numpy

I have created a numpy array,

```
my_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,'qwerty',7,1,4,'qwerty'])
```

I want to replace qwerty with the mean of this array,so how will i calculate mean if both string and int are mixed?
I have tried this and was giving an error

```
new_array = my_array[my_array != 'qwerty'].mean()
```

but this is giving error that
`cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: use arr.astype(float)  before arr.mean()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking the mean you also need to convert your remaining data to floats or ints. You can use `.astype(float)` on the array to accomplish that once the strings have been removed. To replace `qwerty` with the mean you also need to make sure you put the mean in the right location in the array. Try this:

```
my_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,'qwerty',7,1,4,'qwerty'])

new_array=np.copy(my_array) #Create a copy of your array

#calculate the mean and put it into the array where 'qwerty' is true
new_array[my_array == 'qwerty'] = np.mean(my_array[my_array != 'qwerty'].astype(float))
```

Outputs:

```
array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '3.142857142857143', '7', '1', '4',
   '3.142857142857143'], dtype='<U21')
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it doesn't work because your array is converted to strings:

```
>>> my_array
array(['1', '2', '3', '4', 'qwerty', '7', '1', '4', 'qwerty'], dtype='<U21')
```

So you have to change the type to *int* and then you can do the mean operation:

```
a1 = my_array[my_array !='qwerty']
a1 = a1.astype(int)
mean_array = np.mean(a1)
```

Then you can replace your `'qwerty'` elements with the mean:

```
>>> np.where(my_array=='qwerty', str(mean_array), my_array) 
array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '3.142857142857143', '7', '1', '4','3.142857142857143'], dtype='<U21')
```